# HTTP 400 Bad Request when making HTTPS connection in Python?

Tags: python, https

I am getting an `HTTP 400 - Bad Request` error while making an `XML-RPC` over `HTTPS` in Python 3.8.

It seems like this issue is happening when we are supplying the `Host` header in the `HTTPS` request, without `skip_host=True` in the `putrequest` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection.putrequest)) call before that. Are both these info's -- `skip_host` argument and `Host` header, mutually exclusive? If so, which one should I use?

```py
import http.client

connection = http.client.HTTPSConnection("duckduckgo.com", "443")

connection.putrequest("GET", "/")  # needs skip_host=True if Host has to be supplied
connection.putheader("User-Agent", "Python/3.8")
connection.putheader("Host", "duckduckgo.com")  # needs skip_host=True to work
connection.endheaders()

response = connection.getresponse()
print(response.status, response.reason)
```

Update: This issue doesn't happen with all HTTPS servers, as mentioned in the official docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leaving `skip_host` to its default value, i.e., `False`, and specifying a `Host` header using `putheader` results in sending the `Host` header twice (and in this example with different values). This can be checked by setting the `debuglevel` to a positive value.

```py
>>> import http.client
>>> connection = http.client.HTTPSConnection("duckduckgo.com", "443")
>>> connection.set_debuglevel(1)
>>> connection.putrequest("GET", "/")
>>> connection.putheader("User-Agent", "Python/3.8")
>>> connection.putheader("Host", "duckduckgo.com")
>>> connection.endheaders()
send: b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: duckduckgo.com:443\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nUser-Agent: Python/3.8\r\nHost: duckduckgo.com\r\n\r\n'
>>> 
>>> response = connection.getresponse()
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n'
header: Server header: Date header: Content-Type header: Content-Length header: Connection header: X-XSS-Protection header: X-Content-Type-Options header: Referrer-Policy header: Expect-CT
```

In [`http.client`'s code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/http/client.py) it is mentioned that sending the `Host` header twice can be "confusing" for some web servers. See the following comment in `putrequest`:

```
            if not skip_host:
                # this header is issued *only* for HTTP/1.1
                # connections. more specifically, this means it is
                # only issued when the client uses the new
                # HTTPConnection() class. backwards-compat clients
                # will be using HTTP/1.0 and those clients may be
                # issuing this header themselves. we should NOT issue
                # it twice; some web servers (such as Apache) barf
                # when they see two Host: headers
```

Your code will work either by adding `skip_host=True` or by not explicitly specifying a `Host` header. Both result in sending the `Host` header once.

```py
>>> import http.client
>>> connection = http.client.HTTPSConnection("duckduckgo.com", "443")
>>> connection.putrequest("GET", "/", skip_host=True)
>>> connection.putheader("User-Agent", "Python/3.8")
>>> connection.putheader("Host", "duckduckgo.com")
>>> connection.endheaders()
>>> response = connection.getresponse()
>>> print(response.status, response.reason)
200 OK
>>> # OR
>>> connection = http.client.HTTPSConnection("duckduckgo.com", "443")
>>> connection.putrequest("GET", "/")
>>> connection.putheader("User-Agent", "Python/3.8")
>>> connection.endheaders()
>>> response = connection.getresponse()
>>> print(response.status, response.reason)
200 OK
```

As to which one to use, the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection.putrequest) seem to suggest that unless you have a reason to specify a `Host` header (using `putheader`) you can rely on the module's automatic sending of the `Host` header, i.e., leave `skip_host` to its default value, i.e., `False`, and do not specify a `Host` header using `putheader`.

Comment: I read about multiple Host being send somewhere. Appreciate clarifying in depth @Nikolas Chatzis!